# Solving Inhomogeneous Recurrence Relations

Tags: recurrence-relations

Equation is: ${(1/2)(a_n + a_{(n-1)})} = 2n + 5$ when $a_0 = 3$.

So, I got ${a_n = A(-1)^n}$ for the homogenous solution 
I got 2n + 1 for a particular solution to ${a_n = -a_{(n-1)}  + 4n}$ 
I got 5 for  a particular solution to ${a_n = -a_{(n-1)}  + 10}$.

Combined, I used $a_0 = 3$ to get A = -8.
So, I ended up with ${a_n = -8(-1)^n + 2n + 11}$

Is that correct? Or, if not, where did I go wrong?

Update: In my original work, I mistakenly added $10$ instead of $5$. So now, I instead got A = -3 with ${a_n = -3(-1)^n + 2n + 6}$. Is this correct?

Comment: $A(0)=3$ should be a $a_0=3$.

Comment: Combining $2n+1$ and $5$ should yield $2n+6$. Then the corresponding $A$ needs to be changed. But your method is correct.

Comment: Gotcha. I added 10 instead of 5. I just updated my work. Does that look correct now?

Comment: Yes. To confirm that, we have $(1/2)(a_n + a_{n-1}) = (1/2)(-3(-1)^n + 2n + 6 + -3(-1)^{n+1} + 2n + 4) = 2n+5$, and $a_0 = -3 + 0 + 6 = 3$, which matches the recurrence relation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more direct solution. Rewrite your initial relationship under the form:

$$\frac12\left(\underbrace{(a_n-(2n-6))}_{b_n}+\underbrace{(a_{n-1}-(2(n-1)-6))}_{b_{n-1}}\right)=0$$

In this way, you eliminate at once the "non-linearity", giving, as you have done:

$$b_n=A(-1)^n=a_n-(2n-6) \ \iff \ a_n=(2n-6)+A(-1)^n$$

It remains to adjust $A$ in order to comply with the initial value of $a_0$.

We find back your final solution!

Comment: No comment on this solution ?